# Spotify: Search for Artist and Title at the same time

Tags: spotify

I am new to the Spotify API.  I am trying to figure out how to search for an artist and a title at the same time.

I'm using an AJAX call with both artist and title.  If either is blank, I can simply search for the other, but I can not seem to figure out how to search for the artist and title at the same time.  The purpose of this is to narrow down the result to find a specific track.

Here's what I have:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$search_artist = rawurlencode($_POST['search_artist']);
$search_title = rawurlencode($_POST['search_title']);


if($search_artist && !$search_title) {
    //Search for Artist only
    $url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=*".$search_artist."*&type=artist";
} else if(!$search_artist && $search_title) {
    //Search for title only
    $url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=*".$search_title."*&type=track";
} else if($search_artist && $search_title) {
    //Search for Artist AND Title
    $url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=*".$search_artist."*&type=artist&q=*".$search_title."*&type=track";
}

$contents = file_get_contents($url);

echo json_encode($contents);
```

As mentioned, if I search for only artist or only title, it works just fine.  I just don't know how to search for both at the same time using Spotify's API.

Answer (score 1):

If I rephrase your question it sounds like:

- If only search_artist is filled in, you want to the find an artist
- If only search_track is filled in, you want to find a track
- If both are filled in, you still want to find a track

Then the type should just be track.

The documentation also doesn't mention that you can have q and type parameters twice. https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/ It does mention you can search for tracks and artist by having them comma-separated, type=track,artist but reading your question this is probably not what you want.

```
$url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=".$search_artist."+".$search_title."&type=track";
```